# Is the BPP class closed for union and intersection?

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques, complexity-classes, randomness

Just like the title says. I want to prove that given two languages $L_1,L_2 \in BPP$, $L_1 \cup L_2 \in BPP$ and  $L_1 \cap L_2 \in BPP$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T_1$ (resp. $T_2$) a polynomial-time probabilistic Turing machine with error probability of at most $1/3$ for $L_1$ (resp. $L_2$).

Let $T'_1$ (resp. $T'_2$) be a Turing machine for $L_1$ (resp. $L_2$) obtained by running $T_1$ (resp. $T_2$) $9$ times and returning the majority result.
The error probability of $T'_1$ (resp. $T'_2$) is at most $p_F = \sum_{i=5}^9 \binom{9}{i} (1/3)^i (2/3)^{9-i} < \frac{1}{6}$.

A Turing machine for $L_1 \cup L_2$ (resp. $L_1 \cap L_2$) simulates $T'_1$ and $T'_2$ and accepts if and only if at least one of (resp. both of) $T'_1$ and $T'_2$ accept.
By the union bound, the probability of error of this Turing machine is at most $2 \cdot p_F < 2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
In the meantime I found this solution: https://imgur.com/a/O7PwKVO [here](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aIuqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=union+in+bpp+class&source=bl&ots=fYVGKZNufl&sig=ACfU3U262QVGK3JAhpUIkKP5WkIxwkcGKQ&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsjIybuYbqAhWJlhQKHR8yCJEQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=union%20in%20bpp%20class&f=false)

It appears a bit easier to understand than want you answered. What do you think of that solution?

Comment: That is the same approach of my solution, except that I actually showed how to get Turing machines for $L_1$ and $L_2$ with small enough error probabilities instead of just saying "Since $L_1$ and $L_2$ are in BPP, there are two Turing Machines $T'_1$ and $T'_2$ that respectively accept $L_1$ and $L_2$ with a probability of error of at most $1/6$".

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help! :)